# Script to Prevent Google Slides from Opening New Tab When Touched vs. Clicked

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

I created a [digital Pop It in Google Slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vQGV26KW06nsANPmDp9lX8CkLzxXWk3So9cL_R_HgQ055p6q-B19-Gnx-Z_NNIb-BjFW6rvXUhpjBVt/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000) with about 120 slides, which is Published to the Web from the File menu. Each slide has a transparent image overlaying it that is linked to Next Slide. When the user clicks with their mouse on the transparent image, it proceeds to the next slide, and works as it is expected to.

However, when the user has a touch screen, and then presses on the screen to advance it to the next slide, it opens up a new tab and stays on the same slide, and does not advance to the next slide.

Does anyone know of a script that can turn this off so that if a user is pressing on the screen to advance the slide, it will actually work? Or is this a bug?

Thanks for your help!

**FYI: the slide may take a little while to load.**

You can view the slide [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Vke7nNACyERMwqrCxU_goJe9pFFsFPaWP9uo9LRAKP8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: can you add some details on the code(script) if there is any related to this slide then we can help you, otherwise the link just has a slideshow of the google slide which is irrelevant?

Comment: @kl kl I don't have any code in there. Wondering if there's a way to prevent Google Slides from opening up a new tab when the user touches on the slide as compared to clicking, which does not open a new tab in Chrome and behaves as expected, advancing to the next slide.

Comment: ok, can you share this slide over here? not published web version , please share the docs link then we can try to recreate your situation and suggest some solution.From the shared link I see each new slide has a new HTTP link referring to the next slide

Comment: @klkl updated the post that includes a link to it at the bottom. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's not needed to add a transparent image to go to the next slide, because the default behavior is to go to the next slide when clicked. So the default behavior adapts on touch screen devices

Comment: @DavidSalomon that's true, but the pointer doesn't show up unless you add a link, otherwise it's just an arrow. Trying to make it as user friendly as possible for some elementary students Pre-K through 2nd grade. Ha ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it out and apparently it might be a bug. I removed the transparent image with the link to the next slide and the issue is the same.

I recommend you to report it on:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=824111

And describe the issue.

As a workaround, if you open the Google Slides app, it works as intended.